# Importing reactstrap components uses wrong syntax

Tags: javascript, webpack, reactstrap

According to the [docs](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap#adding-bootstrap), I should be able to do this to import a component for use in my React App:

```
import { Alert } from 'reactstrap';
```

However, this will cause webpack to complain like this:

> | Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'reactstrap' in '~/project/client/app/bundles/Frontend/components/team'

Then, I switch the import to this:

```
import Alert from 'reactstrap/lib/Alert';
```

And the import & functionality works!

This probably means (?) some configuration or module exports are not working for this module. Where can I start debugging / fixing this?

Comment: This has to do with how the package is built. There's likely no top level index.js file that exports all the modules as named exports. Instead you have to include them directly from the lib folder. Is this an npm package you've created?

Comment: @shadymoses it's this one https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap and yes, there is no index.js file. Are those index.js files created manually?

Comment: https://github.com/gajus/create-index maybe this one

Comment: And apparently there is a index.js file in src/ already!

Comment: create-index would work but you'd still have to import from reactstrap/lib. It looks like a design decision by the package owner to not have named imports. Previous to version 2, webpack builds would get much smaller by importing modules directly instead of doing named imports. (If I remember correctly)

Comment: You could hack the module if it's just not going to work for you to import them directly from lib. That's just brittle. You would run into problems if you ever wanted to update the package. You could submit an issue on github asking for simpler import syntax and see what they say

Comment: The first import works fine. If it doesn't work for you, you must have changed webpack's resolving, but without your config there is no way to tell what exactly causes the issue. Also an `index.js` is not necessary since it has a `package.json` with [a `main` and a `module` field](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/f6ef08830ae798980ad36889dd94e485bce0d5b1/package.json#L5-L7), which are both checked by webpack by default.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. I had used my fork (to get rid of reacts <15.5 addon dependency but this might have caused other issues). Now I'm using the "official" source, plus installed the addons dependency and it works as documented. Will close the question.